# 2 chamadas para a mesma tabela em SQLite (saída diferente do esperado)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, sqlite3

Dada as 2 seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sugestoes (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    texto  VARCHAR(250),
    autor  VARCHAR(250),
    itens  VARCHAR(250),
    pontos INTEGER
);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vertices (
    id            INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    id_node_pai   INTEGER,
    id_node_filho INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_node_pai)   REFERENCES sugestoes(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_node_filho) REFERENCES sugestoes(id)
);
```

---

[image: tabela sugestoes]

[image: tabela vertices]

[image: resultado]

---

Estou fazendo a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.autor
FROM sugestoes AS s
LEFT JOIN vertices AS v
WHERE s.id <> v.id_node_pai;
```

Afim de obter os resultados da tabela `sugestoes` que não estejam na tabela `vertices`. Quando eu uso o sinal de `=` ele faz a listagem correta, mostrando apenas os resultados iguais (autor 2 e autor 4 do exemplo), porém quando mudo para o sinal de `<>`, o resultado que eu tenho é de todos os nomes de autores da tabela.

Não sei se a falha esta na minha lógica ou na forma como estou elaborando a consulta.

Comment: a sintaxe correta do join seria `LEFT JOIN vertices AS v
ON s.id = v.id_node_pai`

Comment: @RicardoPontual, eu não sei bem qual a diferença entre `WHERE` e `ON`, mas neste meu exemplo a saída foi a mesma, outro ponto, eu não quero os valores iguais, quero justamente os diferentes, quando busco pelos iguais, da certo, porém quando busco os diferentes ele lista todos, independente de serem iguais ou diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu banco de dados for MySQL, tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT autor
FROM sugestoes

MINUS

SELECT s.autor
FROM sugestoes AS s
INNER JOIN vertices AS v ON v.id_node_pai = s.id
```

Comment: Estou usando o SQLite, é uma aplicação pequena para testar, tentei usar esta query e não funcionou, então eu fiz uma pesquisa, pelo que pude ver, o SQLite não tem o comando `MINUS`, mas é recomendado usar o `EXCEPT` no lugar e deu certo.